# Check if signal is in the limits given by another signal

Tags: python, python-2.5

How can I check if a signal is below the limits of a reference signal, with python? Each signal is given as a two-dimensional list, for example like in following code and diagram.

```py
#Signal = [[t0, t1, t2, ...], [y(t0), y(t1), y(t2), ...]]
CapturedSignal = [[1.0, 1.9, 2.0, 3.0, 3.1, 4.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
ReferenceSignal = [[0.5, 2.4, 2.5, 2.7, 2.8, 4.5], [1.2, 1.2, 0.4, 0.4, 1.2, 1.2]]
```

[reference and captured signal http://www.img-host.de/bild.php/35899,caprefsigWQJ8Z.png](http://www.img-host.de/bild.php/35899,caprefsigWQJ8Z.png)

My problem is, that the sampling points of the two signals don't match. I could interpolate between two points to get comparable values but maybe you know ready to use functions in SciPy, NumPy or something else.

Comment: How did you graph the values? Can you use this same tool to compare the values?

Comment: No, I used MS Excel to show the values.

Answer (score 2):

You must use interpolation. It involves always some incertainty (you never know what's between your sampling points) but as long as your sampling rate is sufficiently high, you will be on the safe side.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

from scipy.interpolate import interp1d


CapturedSignal = [[1.0, 1.9, 2.0, 3.0, 3.1, 4.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
ReferenceSignal = [[0.5, 2.4, 2.5, 2.7, 2.8, 4.5], [1.2, 1.2, 0.4, 0.4, 1.2, 1.2]]

representation_captured = interp1d(CapturedSignal[0], CapturedSignal[1], kind="linear")
representation_reference = interp1d(ReferenceSignal[0], ReferenceSignal[1], kind="linear")

min_x = max(min(CapturedSignal[0]), min(ReferenceSignal[0]))
max_x = min(max(CapturedSignal[0]), max(ReferenceSignal[0]))

xs = np.linspace(min_x, max_x, 100, False)

captured_interpolated = representation_captured(xs)
reference_interpolated = representation_reference(xs)

captured_signal_in_bounds = np.all(captured_interpolated<reference_interpolated)

plt.plot(xs, captured_interpolated, "r-", label="Captured")
plt.plot(CapturedSignal[0], CapturedSignal[1], "rD")
plt.plot(xs, reference_interpolated, "b-", label="Reference")
plt.plot(ReferenceSignal[0], ReferenceSignal[1], "bD")
plt.title("Signal below reference" if captured_signal_in_bounds else "Signal exceeds bounds")

plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

results in this plot:

[image: Resuls]

Answer (score 1):

No need to use NumPy for this. You can use [zero-order hold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-order_hold), meaning you assume the signal is constant between samples. This is a simple enough kind of interpolation to code in a few lines.

```
CapturedSignal = [[1.0, 1.9, 2.0, 3.0, 3.1, 4.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
ReferenceSignal = [[0.5, 2.4, 2.5, 2.7, 2.8, 4.5], [1.2, 1.2, 0.4, 0.4, 1.2, 1.2]]

def refat(x):
    "Simple interpolation (Zero-order hold) of reference signal"
    for i, n in enumerate(ReferenceSignal[0]):
        if n > x:
            if i == 0: return None
            return ReferenceSignal[1][i-1]

def capat(x):
    "Simple interpolation of capture signal"
    for i, n in enumerate(CapturedSignal[0]):
        if n > x:
            if i == 0: return None
            return CapturedSignal[1][i-1]   

def aboveref():
    "Check whether there is a captured value above its interpolated reference value and vice versa"
    print ' X  Cap Ref'
    for i, x in enumerate(CapturedSignal[0]):
        cap = CapturedSignal[1][i]
        ref = refat(x)
        print x, cap, ref
        if cap > ref:
            print "Uh oh! At %.1f, the captured signal is above the reference signal!" % x
            return False
    print '---'
    for i, x in enumerate(ReferenceSignal[0]):
        ref = ReferenceSignal[1][i]
        cap = capat(x)
        print x, cap, ref
        if cap > ref:
            print "Uh oh! At %.1f, the captured signal is above the reference signal!" % x
            return False
    return True

aboveref()
```

Result:

```
 X  Cap Ref
1.0 0.0 1.2
1.9 0.0 1.2
2.0 1.0 1.2
3.0 1.0 1.2
3.1 0.0 1.2
4.0 0.0 1.2
---
0.5 None 1.2
2.4 1.0 1.2
2.5 1.0 0.4
Uh oh! At 2.5, the captured signal is above the reference signal!
```